# Why is my docker build command failing with an "invalid id" error?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker on CentOS 7:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.10.3, build 4402420-unsupported
```

I write a very simple test `Dockerfile` as below:

```
FROM docker.oa.com/centos7  #this exists in my Docker
RUN ls
```

When I run the command command

```
$sudo docker build -f dockerfile3  -t test .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM docker.oa.com/centos7
 ---> 1e9b056ba4c7
Step 2 : RUN ls
invalid id:
```

Why can't I build this `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Upgrade your docker. Run `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`

Comment: what did you mean by `docker.oa.com` ? it is invalid
include output of `docker images` command

Comment: @TarunLalwani i,the environment is company internal network，it can not use  curl to update...

Comment: @IAmBatman It's my  company private registry..

Comment: You are using a unsupported build `build 4402420-unsupported`. So it is difficult to say what could be wrong. Also you are at least a year behind the latest version. No point in us debugging this

Comment: @TarunLalwani that's right,thank you very much,i'm so careless to ignore the version log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have docker daemon starting with `--bridge=none --iptables=false`

If you do have the 2 options, and your company won't allow you to use docker without these 2 options, try to update docker to newer versions where you can specify network setting during `docker build`

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22872